# Conky running in startup, but not showing

Tags: gnome, autostart, conky, 21.10

I recently started using conky, and I'm trying to have it run on startup. To do this, I've used the Startup Application program to run a shell script that starts conky. If I run this script manually, it works fine and conky shows up. However, conky doesn't seem to show up on startup. I can tell that the script runs, as I can see conky running in the system monitor, but nothing appears on my desktop.

This is the `.desktop` file that was created:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/home/nick/start_conky
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_CA]=Conky
Name=Conky
Comment[en_CA]=
Comment=
```

And my ubuntu version is 21.10 impish.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly conky is loading before the display is available, so it starts but never connects to the display. Try adding a `--pause=` argument to your conky call.

From `man conky`:

```
--
       -p | --pause= SECONDS
              Time to pause/wait before actually starting Conky.
--
```

I am also running 21.10 and ran into the same issue. Adding `--pause=5` was enough of a delay to resolve the problem. Your timing may vary.

Edit:

I have another system with the same problem and this solution did not fix the problem. https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/issues/1087 suggests this is an issue with conky not waiting for Xwayland to load. I built the most recent version of conky and had the same issue.

As a quick-and-dirty workaround, I changed my startup to a script which calls conky, waits, and then forces conky to reload its configuration:

```
#!/bin/sh

killall conky
/usr/bin/conky -d
sleep 5
killall -SIGUSR1 conky
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working again by updating the startup command

My set up is - Ubuntu 21.10 impish || GNOME 4 || x11

open up startup applications and add or edit you current conky startup command to this:

```
conky --pause=3 & /usr/bin/conky
```

This will delay conky enough to wait until the window has loaded.

If your system takes longer to load, 3 seconds might not be enough. Just play around with it and find the best pause time.

*Edit - I found that a 1 second pause was enough for a seamless startup

[screenshot of startup command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvUDo.png)